# Why does value only update on the next clock pulse?

Tags: verilog

I am simulating the code below and when I change the valid signal the data is put into the line only on the next positive edge why does that happen? I have not done any testbench just simulating in Vivaldo and forcing these values.

[image: screenshot]

```
module lineBuffer(
                  input   i_clk,
                  input   i_rst,
                  input [7:0] i_data,
                  input   i_data_valid,
                  output [23:0] o_data,
                  input i_rd_data
                  );

    reg [7:0] line [511:0]; //line buffer
    reg [8:0] wrPntr;
    reg [8:0] rdPntr;
    always @(posedge i_clk)
    begin
        if(i_data_valid)
          line[wrPntr] <= i_data;
    end

    always @(posedge i_clk)
    begin
        if(i_rst)
          wrPntr <= 'd0;
        else if(i_data_valid)
          wrPntr <= wrPntr + 'd1;
    end

    assign o_data ={line[rdPntr],line[rdPntr+1],line[rdPntr+2]};

    always @(posedge i_clk)
    begin
        if(i_rst)
          rdPntr <= 'd0;
        else if(i_rd_data)
          rdPntr <= rdPntr + 'd1;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way a sequence of hardware flops work. You designed such sequences. Here is an example,

1. at posedge clk you scheduled an update of the *wrPntr*. It will be stored at the output of the first flop, expressed by `wrPntr <= wrPntr + 'd1`.
2. the next flop, `line[wrPntr] <= i_data;` will not see the value of wrPntr evaluated before. It will only see it on the next clock cycle.

```
         +--+      +--+          
         |  |  Q1  |  |
    Q---->  |------>  |----Q2
         +^-+      +^-+
    clk---|---------|
```

In the above, Q2 will have one clock cycle delay in relation to Q

You should really run a simulation to study behavior of different signals.

Comment: Yeah but the value of wrpntr is 0 for quite some time before the I valid so when the first clock hits to which I valid is one the data should be updated on that edge only why does it update on the next edge

Comment: @virenmehra you need to run simulation to figure out all issues with your code.